# Error while building px4_sitl in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, simulation, gazebo-simu, px4

Error while building px4_sitl gazebo... please help me

I referenced [this link](https://docs.px4.io/master/en/simulation/gazebo.html).

input command : `make px4_sitl gazebo`
os : Ubuntu 18.04 lts

Here's my terminal log :

```
xxxx@xxxx-OMEN-30L-Desktop-GT13-1xxx:~/PX4-Autopilot$ make px4_sitl gazebo 

--- skip --- 

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/inhatc/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/build_gazebo/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/inhatc/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/build_gazebo/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
[2/8] Linking CXX executable bin/px4
FAILED: external/Stamp/sitl_gazebo/sitl_gazebo-configure
cd /home/inhatc/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/build_gazebo && /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DSEND_ODOMETRY_DATA=ON -DGENERATE_ROS_MODELS=ON -GNinja /home/inhatc/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/sitl_gazebo && /usr/bin/cmake -E touch /home/inhatc/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/external/Stamp/sitl_gazebo/sitl_gazebo-configure
[4/8] Linking CXX executable bin/px4
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Makefile:230: recipe for target 'px4_sitl' failed
make: *** [px4_sitl] Error 1
```

Comment: I find that same question !
https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/issues/16562

Comment: I have the same problem, can't find a solution right now..